# How do I check and test facebook ads campaign?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to track facebook ads campaign on iOS app.
I am using amplitude, and app_open_source is not tracked that it came from facebook, and as I have launched a paid facebook ads campaign, I would like to know how many people came from the campaign and not other funnels.

So the question is that is it possible and how to test facebook ads without spending own money?
I want to try to click the banners, links to test how the app reacts and how it tracks the banner tap event.